# Need to add a custom LINK with this button

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php if( get_theme_mod('bonfire_touchy_hide_menu_button') == '') { ?>
<div class="touchy-menu-button">
    <div class="touchy-menu-tooltip"></div>
    <span class="touchy-menu-text-label-offset">
        <?php if( get_theme_mod('bonfire_touchy_menu_icon') == '') { ?>
            <div class="touchy-default-menu"></div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <i class="fa <?php echo get_theme_mod('bonfire_touchy_menu_icon') ; ?>"></i>
        <?php } ?>
    </span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Code above is for a button, used in a plugin for Tabs (Wordpres). This button by default is calling MENU. I need to change it to http://www.website/account without changing the css. Override is fine.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom link you need to add the `<a href="#">MENU</a>` tag. And according to that the style should be taken.